# C# Item not being added to List<String>

Tags: c#, list, data-structures, interface

Below is my implementation of ICollector interface from Azure.

```
class TestCollector<T> : ICollector<T>
{
    public List<T> Collector => new List<T>();

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        Collector.Add(item);
    }
}
```

When the item is added on the TestCollector,
the Collector's count still remain as 0.

What is the reason it's not being added?
Should I create a separate constructor for TestCollector and initialize Collector inside?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following is wrong

```
public List<T> Collector => new List<T>();
```

The arrow function is short-hand syntax for a method. What you've written is equivalent to the following:

```
public List<T> Collector()
{
    return new List<T>();
}
```

So every time you call Collector, you return a new list, add an item to it, and then no longer have a reference to that list.

If you need a field, replace it with this:

```
public List<T> Collector = new List<T>();
```

Edit: 
I've missed the fact that you need the Collector method in order to implement your interface. In that case it might make sense to initialise the list in a field, and then return it in your implementation of Collector as follows:

```
class TestCollector<T> : ICollector<T>
{
    private List<T> Collector _collector = new List<T>();
    public List<T> Collector => _collector;

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        _collector.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: A read only auto property with an initializer is a bit cleaner (and clearer) IMO. Though the end result is pretty much the same: `public List<T> Collector { get; } = new List<T>();` if you're going to keep the way you have it, I'd probably access the field inside the `Add` method and not the property

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 would a property still implement the interface that expects a method? Or are you suggesting I replace the field with a property and still return it via the method? If it's the latter I'm not sure I see the benefit.

I do agree that it makes sense to access the field over the method though.

Comment: Other than the code I include in my comment, I was suggesting you change your Add method to `public void Add(T item) { _collector.Add(item);}`

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Yes that's the bit I agree with, will edit now, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 5):

You are creating a new list every time

Don't do this

```
public List<T> Collector => new List<T>();
```

Do this

```
public List<T> Collector = new List<T>();
```

or

```
public List<T> Collector { get; } = new List<T>();
```